# I need a script to automatically print files that I upload to a skydrive folder

Tags: windows, printing, onedrive, phone

I want to print any file that I upload to a specific skydrive folder.

I want to be able to print from my WP8, but of course Windows Phone 8 doesn't support that. Does anyone have any thoughts? It seems like I've seen this before, but I can't find any answers to my searches.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a Google search, [PrintFile](http://www.lerup.com/printfile/descr.html) comes up in several results.  It looks like you will be able to point it to your local Skydrive folder on your PC and have it print out your files.

Answer (score 0):

There's a program called Belvedere that I believe you could use to do that.

http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc

I haven't used it yet, but I did play around with it a bit and it has the ability to create a rule (all files in "Skydrive" folder, for example) and perform an action on any files meeting the conditions (print, copy, rename, etc.)

So, you would select your Skydrive folder, create a new rule, and set it up to print newly uploaded files.